# How do I exit a While(true) loop with a key?

Tags: c#, .net, loops, while-loop

So I have this while loop that looks something like this.

```
bool isTrue = true;
while(isTrue)
{
  //Do work over and over
}
```

I'm wondering.. Can I add if statement that checks if a key has been pressed during the current loop to break out of it? WITHOUT INTERRUPTING THE LOOP so some sort of async task maybe? Because it's automating the task over and over again. For the sake of the question let's say it's printing out ***"Hello World!"*** to the console every third second.

Comment: What kind of work is happening in `Do work over and over`? You should show us this code. It might make a big difference with what is the best answer.

Comment: checkout Console.KeyAvailable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: but if u wanna do something periodically (each 3 seconds) use BackgroundWorker class

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great idea to use a `while` loop like this. The suggestion that you're writing something to the console every one third of a second suggests that you're using a `Thread.Sleep` to wait that time out.

It's far better to use a timer or some other library that let's you do this kind of thing. I'd suggest Microsoft's Reactive Framework. Then you can do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 3.0))
        .TakeWhile(_ => !Console.KeyAvailable)
        .Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        });
```

Job done. If you want to stop the subscription early just call `subscription.Dispose()`.

NuGet "System.Reactive" to get the bits you need.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply just have it as a condition in your while loop. While (true and condition) {} or you can just do an if statement in the body with a break.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to set up a class so that you can have a shared property available in different methods.

```
public class MyLooper
{
    private bool KeepLooping { get; set; } = true;

    public void OnKeyPressed()
    {
        KeepLooping = false;
    }

    public void StartLoop()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            while (KeepLooping)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Hello World");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You haven't indicated where you'd be running this e.g. server, desktop app, console etc but you may encounter and need to tackle thread safety issues.